# Mapping in subsxribe cause undefined error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have method to get data from BE

Here is it

```
 getChartsData(): any {
const documentStyle = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
const textColor = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--text-color');
const textColorSecondary = documentStyle.getPropertyValue(
  '--text-color-secondary'
);
const surfaceBorder = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--surface-border');

this._testFileService.getFileData().subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(
    result.map((obj: any) => {
      obj.city;
    })
  );
```

}

My problem that `console.log(result);` return array of 369 objects

But `console.log( result.map((obj: any) => { obj.city; }) );`

Return undefined

How I can solve this?

My problem that

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a return statement :

```
this._testFileService.getFileData().subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(
    result.map((obj: any) => {
      return obj.city; // <== don't forget the return 
    }
  );
```

You can also shorten it if the return is quite simple like:

```
result.map((obj: any) => obj.city)
```